# AWS EMR import external library from S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I have setup a cluster using Amazon EMR.
I have a python library (cloned from github and not available on pip) on S3.

I want to submit a pig work that uses a udf which makes use of the library present in S3.

I don't want to add the library to the system path because it will be used only once.

I have not been able to try anything meaningful because i am at loss at how to approach this problem, hence do not have any code samples or methods i have tried so far. Help will be deeply appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

carefully read the following given material.

**Call User Defined Functions from Pig:**

Pig provides the ability to call user defined functions (UDFs) from within Pig scripts. You can do this to implement custom processing to use in your Pig scripts. The languages currently supported are Java, Python/Jython, and JavaScript. (Though JavaScript support is still experimental.)

The following sections describe how to register your functions with Pig so you can call them either from the Pig shell or from within Pig scripts. For more information about using UDFs with Pig, go to http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/udf.html.

**Call JAR files from Pig:**

You can use custom JAR files with Pig using the REGISTER command in your Pig script. The JAR file is local or a remote file system such as Amazon S3. When the Pig script runs, Amazon EMR downloads the JAR file automatically to the master node and then uploads the JAR file to the Hadoop distributed cache. In this way, the JAR file is automatically used as necessary by all instances in the cluster.

**To use JAR files with Pig**

1.Upload your custom JAR file into Amazon S3.

2.Use the REGISTER command in your Pig script to specify the bucket on Amazon     S3 of the custom JAR file.

```
REGISTER s3://mybucket/path/mycustomjar.jar;
```

**Call Python/Jython Scripts from Pig**

You can register Python scripts with Pig and then call functions in those scripts from the Pig shell or in a Pig script. You do this by specifying the location of the script with the register keyword.

Because Pig is written in Java, it uses the Jython script engine to parse Python scripts. For more information about Jython, go to http://www.jython.org/.

**To call a Python/Jython script from Pig**

1.Write a Python script and upload the script to a location in Amazon S3. This should be a bucket owned by the same account that creates the Pig cluster, or that has permissions set so the account that created the cluster can access it. In this example, the script is uploaded to

```
s3://mybucket/pig/python.
```

2.Start a pig cluster. If you'll be accessing Pig from the Grunt shell, run an interactive cluster. If you're running Pig commands from a script, start a scripted Pig cluster. In this example, we'll start an interactive cluster.

3.Because we've launched an interactive cluster, we'll now SSH into the master  node where we can run the Grunt shell. For more information about how to SSH into the master node, see SSH into the Master Node.

4.Run the Grunt shell for Pig by typing pig at the command line.

```
pig
```

5.Register the Jython library and your Python script with Pig using the register keyword at the Grunt command prompt, as shown in the following, where you would specify the location of your script in Amazon S3.

```
grunt> register 'lib/jython.jar';
grunt> register 's3://mybucket/pig/python/myscript.py' using jython as myfunctions;
```

6.Load the input data. The following example loads input from an Amazon S3 location.

```
grunt> input = load 's3://mybucket/input/data.txt' using TextLoader as (line:chararray);
```

7.You can now call functions in your script from within Pig by referencing them using myfunctions.

```
grunt> output=foreach input generate myfunctions.myfunction($1);
```